# How to convert Wordpress caption tag to html div tag

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, preg-replace, caption

I converted a webiste from Wordpress and I some of the posts have a caption tag as the following:

```
[caption id="attachment_666" align="alignleft" width="316"]
    <img class="wp-image-92692" src="img" width="316"  alt="fitbit-yoga-lady.png" height="210">   
    text
[/caption]
```

I would like to catch all of these captions and convert it to the following

```html
<div id="attachment_666" style="width: 326px" class="wp-caption alignleft">
  <img class="wp-image-92692" src="img" alt="fitbit-yoga-lady.png" width="316" height="210">
  <p class="caption">text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Presumably you are okay with having the `alt` attribute not get set, or you have some other way of inserting it into the output, since that value does not appear anywhere in the input?

Comment: @StevenDoggart Thanks, I corrected my code, the image tag won't be changed, it is just the caption will be converted to div and the text will be converted to text inside a paragraph with a class name.

Comment: How do I do the same in javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, given the exact text that you provided, the following should work.

Search Pattern:

```
\[caption([^\]]+)align="([^"]+)"\s+width="(\d+)"\](\s*\<img[^>]+>)\s*(.*?)\s*\[\/caption\]
```

Replacement:

```
<div\1style="width: \3px" class="wp-caption \2">\4
    <p class="caption">\5</p>
</div>
```

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/6OO9BT/1).

Depending on how tolerant of variations in the input it needs to be, you may need to adjust it from there, but that should at least get you started.

Here's an example of how this could be done with `preg_replace`:

```
function convert_caption($content) 
{ 
    return preg_replace(
        '/\[caption([^\]]+)align="([^"]+)"\s+width="(\d+)"\](\s*\<img[^>]+>)\s*(.*?)\s*\[\/caption\]/i', 
        '<div\1style="width: \3px" class="wp-caption \2">\4<p class="caption">\5</p></div>', 
        $content); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked for me: how can I converted to global?

function convert_caption($content) {
 $content = preg_replace('/\[caption([^\]]+)align="([^"]+)"\s+width="(\d+)"\](\s*\<img[^>]+>)\s*(.*?)\s*\[\/caption\]/', '<div\1style="width: \3px" class="wp-caption \2">\4<p class="caption">\5</p></div>', $content) . '</p>';
 return $content;
}

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this blindly on my phone, but I *think* you can use the following two regular expressions, one for the opening tag and another for the closing:

Find:
`\[caption([^\]])\]`
Replace:
`<div$1>`

Find:
`\[/\caption\]`
Replace:
`</div>`